# How to work with zero denominators when averaging over fixed time intervals (months/weeks/years)

Tags: r, time-series, analytics, average, data-analysis

Sometimes we want to get the average of a column, say `total_sales`, over an elapsed period of time such as `months_since_posted`:

```
average_sales_per_month = total_sales / months_since_posted
```

But there are cases when it hasn't been a month since a product was posted on site. Thus `average_sales_per_month` becomes divided by zero.

How would you handle such cases? I don't know if this is bad practice, but I would just add a `+ 0.5` on the denominator to estimate a half-month occurrence.

Comment: Maybe calculate in another unit of time? (Days?)

Answer (score 0):

Whatever the problem that you want solve, you should not add arbitary value to your dataset. For a better solution i think you should somehow get the days passed since posted and convert this time to month then divide this value to total sales.